# Div/Button with a circle shaped container to the left of it

Tags: css, css-shapes

Can I ask a little help about creating that shape with CSS?

[image: advanced css shape]

The button needs a circle for the icon, and the simple box for the text.

Comment: Is the icon the person in a brown circle or do you need to create the circle?

Comment: Btw the solution is: `border-radius 50%` to first div.

Comment: I've tried to find something about that, without success. I think, it must be done something with the :before/:after selector.

Comment: I need only the shape. The circle with the box.

Comment: Thank you Harry, I'we checked it now! How can I mark the question to answered, with comments 'only'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a possible version using the `:before` pseudo element. The pseudo element is converted into a circle by using `border-radius: 50%` and is then positioned before the rectangular `div#menu` as required.

You can add a image (like the one in question) to the pseudo element by using the `content` property like shown below:

```
content: url(http://yoursite.com/yourimage.png);
```

or using the `background-image` property also:

```
background-image: url(http://yoursite.com/yourimage.png);
```

```css
#menu {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 24px;
  line-height: 24px;
  color: white;
  background-color: peru;
  border: 1px solid peru;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding-left: 24px;
}
#menu:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  top: -9px; /* (height of parent - height of pseudo) / 2 - border-top of parent for vertical mid */
  /* top: -17px;  (height of parent - height of pseudo) - border-top of parent for bottom align */
  left: -24px; /* some value less than width - depends on amount of overlap needed */
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/40/40/people/1);
  background-color: peru;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

/* Just for demo */

* {
  font-family: Calibri;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}
#menu {
  margin: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div id='menu'>Menu Text</div>
```

**Note:** This is in essence a different version of the answer posted by Jason Gennaro. If you need support for IE lower versions, use his answer because they don't support `:before`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick and dirty version:

**HTML**

```
<div id="circle"></div>
<div id="rectangle">Header Text</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#circle{
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 85px;
    height: 85px; 
    background: brown;
    float:left;
}

#rectangle{
    width:300px;
    height:40px;
    background:brown;
    color:white;
    float:left;
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-left:-40px;
    position:relative;
    z-index:-1;
    padding-left:60px;
    padding-top:6px;
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:2em;
}
```

**DEMO**

http://jsfiddle.net/H6Lkk/

**Explanation**

1. use `border-radius:50%` and any `width` to create a circle.
2. `float` the two divs to allow for the overlap
3. use `position` and `z-index` to place the rectangle under the circle
4. add the logo `image` as necessary in the `#circle`

Comment: Thank you too for the help! Unfortunately I can check only one answer as accepted. :(